# Difference between dbms_job and pragma autonomous transaction

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

whats the difference between dbms_job and pragma autonomous transaction

Comment: Simple Google search on each would have helped you, rather than asking a question on a site which is meant mainly for programming queries.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the fact that they are spelled differently? They are as similar as apples and bananas.

`DBMS_JOB` package schedules and manages jobs in the job queue. It is used to run certain procedures at scheduled time. For example, every day at 02:00, 08:00 and 16:00; or, every Saturday at 12:00, etc. If you're on Windows, it is similar to its Task Manager. Or, on Unix, it is called *Cron*.

It has a *younger brother* called `DBMS_SCHEDULER` which provides a lot more options. Though, for simple jobs, I still use `DBMS_JOB`. More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_job.htm#ARPLS019

---

`Pragma` signifies that the statement is a pragma (compiler directive). Pragmas are processed at compile time, not at run time. They pass information to the compiler.

The `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` pragma changes the way a subprogram works within a transaction. A subprogram marked with this pragma can do SQL operations and commit or roll back those operations, without committing or rolling back the data in the main transaction.

It is usually used to log certain information from your procedures, without affecting the main procedure (because pragma allows the *logging* procedure commit its inserts into the log table, without affecting the main procedure - it can even fail (and implicitly rollback), but your log info will remain intact and available for review).

People misuse it when solving mutating tables error; true, this pragma "fixes" the issue, but is usually a WRONG way to solve that problem.

More info about autonomous transactions here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/static.htm#LNPLS00609

Comment: *"They are as similar as apples and bananas."* More like they are as similar as apples and fruit pies. Not all fruit pies contain apple, not all apples end up in a pie :)